# Gurobi Python - Add certain vars

Tags: gurobi

I'm new to Gurobi and I'd like to know how to add certain variables to a model. For example, if I have an uncomplete graph, I'd like to add a variable x[i,j] for each arc of the graph. I don't want to add all the arcs of the complete graph, because it has a huge number of nodes and my computer runs out of memory. So I'm trying to avoid defining variables with lists for it's indexes.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: I'm using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you know arcs that you want to add. If it is that, you can define a set (list ou dict) of arcs like Arcs={(i,j): value of arc (i,j)}. This set concern only arcs that you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

This is illustrated in the [netflow.py](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/examples/netflow_py.html) example, which can be found in the examples\python subdirectory.